# How can images embedded in google docs be accessed when the doc is exported as html?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Using the PHP drive API I can download an html version of a google native doc via a url in exportLinks["text/html"] in a File resource. However, images embedded in the document seem to be stripped out. How can I retrieve these embedded images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google now appears to fully support images when exporting to html. When I export a Google doc to html, my images appear as:

`<img src="lh3.googleusercontent.com/<buncha_hash_garbage>">`

as I would expect, with the file ID of the image embedded somewhere in the hash.